# Create a heatmap from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandasql

I have a pandas dataframe of the form:

```
colA |   colB   | counts
car1    plane1     23
car2    plane2     51
car1    plane2     12
car2    plane3     41
```

I first want to create a pandas dataframe that looks a bit like a matrix ([similar to the df in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57508626/create-custom-heatmap-from-pandas-dataframe)), also filling the missing values with 0. So the desired result for the above would be:

```
      plane1     plane2     plane3

car1    23         12         0
car2    0          51         41
```

And then be able to turn this into a heat map. Is there a pandas command I can use for this?

Comment: `pd.pivot_table(df, index='colA', columns='colB', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)`?

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to transform data, [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to create a heatmap

```py
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

piv = pd.pivot_table(df, index='colA', columns='colB', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
piv.columns = piv.columns.droplevel(0)

sns.heatmap(piv)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]